# Character degrees of solvable group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, normal-subgroups, characters, solvable-groups

Let G is a non-abelian solvable group and N is minimal normal subgroup of G. I want to show that |cd(G/N)| < |cd(G)| (Inequality is strict) .

Is it true? How could I show that?

We know this is not true for abelian group since if G is abelian then  |cd(G/N)| = |cd(G)| =1

Or in a  simple way, can we say that for a solvable group G , exists a minimal normal subgroup N such that|cd(G/N)| < |cd(G)| .

Answer (score 2):

A minimal counterexample would have the property that $|G/N|$ is at least $6$, since it cannot be abelian either. Thus $|G|\geq 12$. The most obvious non-abelian group of order $12$, the dihedral group, is a counterexample. Generally, $D_{2^n}$ is a counterexample for $n\geq 4$.

More generally than $D_{12}$, $G\times A$, where $G$ is any non-abelian group and $A$ is an abelian group will do, where $N$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.